# Is conscription incompatible with democracy?

Tags: political-theory, military, conscription

Is mandatory military service incompatible with democracy, in which people supposedly are given choices?

Comment: What do you mean by "mandatory army system country"?

Comment: Why would it be incompatible? A country still needs to defend itself and if it isn't able to do that it isn't serving its citizens.

Comment: Well it is the citizen that made up the army, so citizen serving citizen, there is no choice. But it is true that a pure democracy, when one would have the choice not to do the army, would be a set of questions implying nothing. So a democracy needs a totalitarian system to 'push' people to do something. Mandatory means that a certain class of the population has this duty, like a cast system if you want.

Comment: If you disagree with the draft, vote for politicians who want to end the draft.  If enough of your fellow citizens feel the same way, it will get ended.  What's the problem?  BTW, lots of democracies have stopped the draft, so this is not just a theoretical solution.

Comment: As mentioned, if people vote for military service, it's possible in a democracy. You could argue whether compulsory military service is compatible with conceptions of human rights, which though often linked with democracy are a separate thing. It's possible to be a democracy without human rights (e.g. a populist tyranny of the majority), and at least theoretically possible to have some human rights without democracy (benign dictatorship or colonial rule).

Answer (score 3):

No.

To start with, the definition you give for Democracy:

> A system of government where people are given choices.

Is not widely held to be the proper definition.  A more accurate version would be:

> A system of government where law and policy are dictated by popular vote.

So long as the law requiring compulsory military service was arrived at via popular vote, then it is a democratically enacted law.  End of analysis.

All sorts of behaviors are prohibited/required by the laws passed, these violations of freedom (and all laws are such violations) do not invalidate a democracy... why should a compulsory service law?  There may be other principles that are violated by such a law, but the validity of the democracy is not among them.

Comment: A conscription could indicate the country is a shelter for dictators seeking a huge army to invade other places. But psychologically a forced duty can induce a lack of motivation. That the law is dictated by popular vote is far from reality, the questions the government asks will certainly not concern the things the government wants to dictate. And popular initiatives are rejected most of the time, if they pass the government just say it is inapplicable and needs modification. It is not because it is voted that it is won.

Comment: @Cretin2 Democracy, as a concept, doesn't care what the policy outcome of the process is, only that the process itself is observed.  If there's another question you'd like to ask, then go for it, but the question you asked was whether or not the concept of democracy was invalidated by a given policy.

Comment: You mean that if suddenly an elected committee pass in votation : would you like to never vote again ?,  This would mean democracy can suicide and there is no trap ?

Comment: @Cretin2 Yep. Democracies can, in fact, ruin themselves. History has several examples, the most internet-accessible one being the German Diet voting, in 1933, to make Adolf Hitler a dictator. Just as kings can abdicate, democracies can decide to end themselves if that is the will of the voters.  This doesn't invalidate democracy as a concept, nor does it make the dissolution of the democracy un-democratic (though, obviously, whatever else follows sure as heck is).

Comment: Thanks for your interesting comment. There is also the more insidious disease of democracy : in fact questions are orders in disguise, or just a diversion, so that it is not a choice. For de

Comment: Something like a tongue twisting government.

Comment: "The condition upon which God hath given liberty to man is eternal vigilance." - J.P. Curran, circa 1790

Comment: Isn't G-d simply the absolute dictator of the whole universe ? It controls everyone completely, but its voices are incomprehensible. But I see democracy as a result of contradiction of duality : one always contradicts the other so that as a whole both are neutral and cannot decide, so obeying people around ask themselves : so what do we do, there is a lack of orders ?

Comment: But this apart, why would a democracy need to build a military dictatorship, since both systems are said to be ennemies ? And why would conscripted people be happy to follow a totalitarian system to serve that democracy ?

Comment: At a higher level it were like if there were a democracy of the whole humanity and humanity would vote "yes" to the question : "would you like to disappear as a specie ?"